# How to run Fabric commands on Vagrant

Tags: python, vagrant, fabric

How do you use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) to script commands on [Vagrant-managed](https://www.vagrantup.com/) VMs?

I thought it was as simple as [this example](http://sysadminpy.com/sysadmin/2011/04/30/use-fabric-on-vagrant-instances/), but I can't get it to work.

Vagrant by itself is working fine. I can run:

```
vagrant init
vagrant up --provider=libvirt
vagrant ssh
```

and connect through ssh just fine. However, using the Fabric example, if I try and run:

```
fab vagrant uname
```

it fails to connect with the error:

```
[127.0.0.1:2222] Executing task 'test_dev_env'
[127.0.0.1:2222] run: uname -a

Fatal error: Low level socket error connecting to host 127.0.0.1 on port 2222: Connection refused (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
    Connection refused

Aborting.
```

What is causing this error? As far as I know, `vagrant ssh` should be running the same ssh command as Fabric. But sure enough, even if I manually run the ssh command:

```
ssh -i /myproject/.vagrant/machines/default/libvirt/private_key -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1
```

I also get the error:

```
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is going to be wrong if you are trying to login to the VM. Take a look at `vagrant ssh-config`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, vagrant doesn't actually setup a port-forwarder, so the only way to connect to the VM is to get it's IP from `vagrant ssh-config` and then connect using that. So the correct vagrant Fabric task looks like:

```
@task
def vagrant():
    result = local('vagrant ssh-config', capture=True)

    hostname = re.findall(r'HostName\s+([^\n]+)', result)[0]
    port = re.findall(r'Port\s+([^\n]+)', result)[0]
    env.hosts = ['%s:%s' % (hostname, port)]

    env.user = re.findall(r'User\s+([^\n]+)', result)[0]
    env.key_filename = re.findall(r'IdentityFile\s+([^\n]+)', result)[0]
```

Comment: This looks like it would work!  But why would you regex parse the output of `vagrant ssh-config` when you can specify the port in the Vagrantfile?

Comment: I couldn't get Vagrant to work that way. Nothing was running on my local machine at the ports Vagrant claims to be forwarding on.

Answer (score -1):

[By default Vagrant](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) seems to forward tcp port 22 (ssh) to localhost port 4567.

To listen on port 2222 instead, include this in your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2222, id: 'ssh'
```